# Javascript function to check for even/odd numbers

Tags: javascript, function

I tried to make a function in JavaScript that tells if a number is even or not or if it is a number at all. I receive this Error: [image]

It is for a lesson in CodeCademy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking if the function `isNaN` exists, not if the number is `NaN` like `isNaN(number)`.

And while a string with content is truthy, the result is true for any number.

Answer (score 0):

isNaN is a function, so your else if(isNaN) should always be true, since isNaN is a valid function. Try `else if (isNaN(number))` and you should probably check for isNaN before you try modulo, since if you input a string, it'll error immediately when you try to get the module of a string.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a string.

```
else if(isNan){
    return "Whatever";
}
```

you are just telling javascript to evaluated "isNan", as a value, not as a function. To evaluate it as a function, you must use it to make a **call** like this:

```
else if(isNan(yourNumber)){
    return true;
}
```

by the way, when you try to evaluate a function as a value like you did, javascript will always return true if that function is not undefined or null.

Answer (score 0):

It is because

```
else if(isNaN)
```

Will be `true` and return `"This is not a number"` and this string will be considered as true. Here you are checking `isNaN` is defined as a function or not, which is ofcourse defined, So you should check where number is valid number or not.

Instead, you should be doing

```
else if(isNaN(number))
```